# Hapi testing not loading plugins correctly

Tags: hapi.js

Server:

```
server.register({
  register: require('hapi-mongodb'),
  options: config.db.mongo,

}, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
    if (!module.parent) {
      server.start((err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`Server started`);
      });
  }
});
```

In my test:

```
server.inject(options, function(response)...
```

This does not load plugins before the route is called. It's like it doesn't wait for `next()` to be called when the plugin registers itself. For example in this dummy plugin I create a delay before calling `next()`. But by that time the server has already handled the route call.

```
exports.register = function (plugin, options, next) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Loaded after the route is called');
    next();
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Thanks to some help on the Hapi site I was able to do it by listening to the server events:

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
  server.ext('onPreStart', function() {
    done();
  });
});
```

I'll add that you cannot do this common behavior:

```
if (!module.parent) {
 server.start((err) => {
```

And instead must allow the test to start the server as well. So remove the `module.parent` check.